Movie or TV show about a man who could only be hurt when a specific color showed up
I'm looking for a movie or TV-show in which a man couldn't get hurt except when a specific color showed up, I believe red but I could be wrong. This must be a really old film. Could be 70's or 80's era. I remember watching it on TV. All I remember it was a comedy. I can't confirm it was a TV show or a movie, but it felt more like a movie.

That could be Super Fuzz from 1980 with Terrence Hill. A cop gains super powers through a nuclear explosion but looses them whenever he sees the color that he saw at the moment of the explosion which is red.
